# "Flatten" or "Merge" Quartz 2D drawn lines

Tags: objective-c, quartz-2d, lines

I'm trying to figure out how you can flatten or merge alot of dynamicly drawn lines in Quartz 2D,

I'm drawing random lines over time on my stage, I add new line coordinates each time to an array and draw the array (with my drawRect and I push a new line in my array with a timer and a setNeedDisplay to acctually redraw all the previous lines plus the new one)

now the PROBLEM: after a while it starts to get slower and slower because the arrays are getting **very long**, so I though I should merge the coordinates into a flat image or something and clear the arrays to keep it memory healthy, **but how do I do this?**

This is my current workflow:

- Call timer

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1  target:self selector:@selector(drawdrawdraw) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
- Refresh the drawRect in my "drawdrawdraw" function

  -(void)drawdrawdraw{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
  }
- my drawRect

  ```
  -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
      viewContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

      int count = [mijnArray_r_x count];

      float r_x = (float)(random() % 768);
      [mijnArray_r_x insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:r_x] atIndex:count];

      float r_y = (float)(random() % 1004);
      [mijnArray_r_y insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:r_y] atIndex:count];

      float r_w = (float)(random() % 100);
      [mijnArray_r_w insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:r_w] atIndex:count];

      float r_a = (float)(random() % 100);
      [mijnArray_r_a insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:r_a] atIndex:count];


      CGContextSetLineWidth(viewContext, 2.0);
      CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(viewContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
      for (int k = 0; k <= count; k++) {

          float temp_x = [[mijnArray_r_x objectAtIndex: k] floatValue];
          float temp_y = [[mijnArray_r_y objectAtIndex: k] floatValue];
          float temp_w = [[mijnArray_r_w objectAtIndex: k] floatValue];
          float temp_a = [[mijnArray_r_a objectAtIndex: k] floatValue];

          CGPoint pointpointpoint = CGPointMake(temp_x, temp_y);
          CGPoint pointpointpointpoint = CGPointMake(temp_w, temp_a);
          CGContextMoveToPoint(viewContext, pointpointpoint.x, pointpointpoint.y);
          CGContextAddLineToPoint(viewContext, pointpointpoint.x - pointpointpointpoint.x, pointpointpoint.y + pointpointpointpoint.y);
          CGContextStrokePath(viewContext);
      }
  } }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw your lines into a `UIImage` by using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`. This way, the time needed to draw will be constant, because in each iteration you're only drawing the cached image as a bitmap and the new lines you add.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [self.currentImage drawInRect:[self bounds]];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self bounds].size);
  CGContextRef cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  //Draw your lines into the cgContext here...
  self.currentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

This assumes that you have the property `currentImage` of type `UIImage` declared.